# MIPS .data Segment to Machine Code

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code

I have to convert the following code from the .data segment into machine code, but I am unsure as to how this is done.

```
value: .word  -39
```

I understand the process for .asciiz variables, but I cannot find any information on .word variables to machine code.

Also, does the processor assemble the .data segment or the .text segment first? I would think .data since its first in the written code, but I just want to be sure. (I have to associate hex addresses to their respective machine code in order, and I assume this would be the first machine code.)

Comment: The `.data`-segment is not converted to machine code.

Comment: You might be asking how to represent signed integers in binary. In that case look at [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Well for the assignment that I'm doing it says specifically to "do both the .data and .text sections." If its true that the .data segment is not translated, should I just ignore the instructions for this part? (It gives a specific address that the machine code is apparently supposed to be as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.word` tells the assembler

- the size of the following list of expressions (usually `.word` is two bytes, i.e. 16 bit)
- the byte order (most significant byte in higher or lower address)

which both are depending on the target machine you are assembling for

For negative numbers - as suggested - usually a 2's complement is used, so as a byte -39 would translate to `0xD9` or `0b11011001`.

As you have declared this constant `.word`, -39 is stored as a 16 bit value, i.e. `0xFFD9`.

```
value: .word -39
```

hence could also be declared "more machine coded" as

```
value: .byte 0xD9, 0xFF ; little endian architecture - LSB(yte) at lower address
```

or

```
value: .byte 0xFF, 0xD9 ; big endian architecture - LSB(yte) at higher address
```

with `.byte` always filling up memory from the lower to the higher address.

Comment: I thought .word was 4 bits and halfword was 2 bytes? EDIT: Wait I'm wrong. You said bytes not bits whoops.

Comment: as I wrote ... depending on your machine ... for a MIPS architecture you are correct, `.word` is 4 byte, so the byte flow from lower to higher address is D9 FF FF FF (little endian)